# Drop shadow not appearing on li elements

Tags: css

I'm adapting a [technique shown](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-getting-clever-with-css3-shadows/) on net.tutsplus.com regarding cool shadow effects on elements.

Now, for some reason, after my elements all sequentially appear on the page, there are no proper shadows.  They are completely hidden.

For some reason however, as they are sequentially appearing, you can sort of notice the shadow.

If someone can help identify the problem, that would be fantastic!

Problem may be seen [here](http://www.marioplanet.com/tiletabs/index.html).

Comment: Seems to work on Chrome. Edit - FYI the methods you use to show shadow are not cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Really?  So, there's a little drop shadow coming out of the right side of each "tile"?  I'm on a Mac, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hey guys.  Sorry for the pestering, but I just wanted to make sure.  Did you guys click through the first link in my OP to see the technique done at net.tutsplus?  Because, I checked on Chrome on a Vista box, and the shadow didn't show up properly either.

Answer (score 1):

The shadows are working for me in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. You are using the correct CSS elements for all these browsers. However, any browsers (such as Internet Explorer) that do not support the CSS3 shadow elements will be unable to show this effect.

There are alternative ways to get shadows to work cross-browser using nested `<div>`s and `background-image`s or JavaScript. I know there are many jQuery plugins that achieve this. It all comes down to how important shadows are to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  For some reason though, the shadows do not properly appear on Chrome, Firefox and Safari on a Mac running Snow Leopard.